# Length of an edge

Tags: pythagorean-triples

My sister asked me to help her with her homework for mathematics, however frustratingly I was not able to figure out how to solve it.

The assignment is as follows where it was requested to calculate the length between G and I. How should this assignment be solved?

[image: Diagram of triangles]

Thanks!

Comment: Please include your sister's effort as well as your attempts to solve it.

Comment: What has this to do with `Pythagorean-triples`?

Comment: As general advice, always compute what you can compute.   Here, $\overline {HE}$ is easy.  From that you can get $\overline {GE}$.  Now you've got two right triangles left that you haven't used...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a messy plane geometry and algebra problem.  All the following using Pythagorean theorem.  First $|H-E|=4$, then $|E-G|^2=32$.  Let $x=|E-I|$ and $h=|G-I|$.  The equation for $x$ and $h$ are $x^2+h^2=32$ and $(5-x)^2+h^2=49$.  Solving these equations gives $x=.8$ and $h=5.6$, where $h$ is the answer to the problem.

Comment: The use of Cartesian coordinates (analytic geometry) may be outside the scope of the course material this exercise was intended to reinforce.

Comment: Thanks herb steinberg, this is indeed the way she was expected to solve it! My sister got some algebra lectures a while ago, so she apparently had to combine it with the current lectures about the pythagorean theorem. Nice ingenious way of solving it, thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Let $$\angle{EFG}=\alpha$$ then $$\cos(\alpha)=\frac{3}{5}$$ and $$\sin(\alpha)=\frac{GI}{7}$$

Comment: I'd be concerned that trigonometry may be outside the scope of the course material this exercise was intended to reinforce.

Comment: Thanks Dr. Sonnhard Graubner for your response. So far she hasn't got lectures about trigonometry, but nice to see there are multiple ways to solve it.